# What would you recommend me to record videos while playing Xbox360

Tags: video, digital-recording, hardware

I would like to record some videos while playing on the Xbox360. I've been looking around and I would prefer to not use the PC to record (a PCIe card, for example) and I've come across the following recorder:

http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/hyperdeckshuttle/

And I would like to know if anyone knows it or has used it. Also I would like to know if it is good and worth the money it costs. Or is there any other better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The hyperdeck shuttle is a small, lightweight and easy-to-use field recorder. The downside it just works with expensive SSD volumes.

A possible alternative could be the Atomos Ninja. - Pros: Runs with SSD, but also with cheap and capacious 2.5-inch-HDDs. Built-in Touch-LCD-screen. Double battery connectors. The drives and batteries are hot-swapable. Cons: It's weight and it's size.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Intensity cards from Blackmagic](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/). They're pretty affordable and rock solid.